# Is MPI_Ibcast buffered?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I'm using OpenMPI for a little project, and I've got a doubt.
When I use MPI_Ibcast to send an array to all the other processes, can I start computing on the same array?

Example:

```
MPI_Ibcast(array, ... &request);
compute(array);
MPI_Wait(&request);
```

If I get it right, MPI_Ibcast does not save the array in a buffer, so I couldn't do that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *any* `MPI_Iwhatever` operation you should not touch the buffer before the completion (the `MPI_Waitwhatever` call). If it's a sending call (including a `bcast` if you're the root) the data may not have been sent; if it's a receiving call (including `bcast` if you're not the root) there is no guarantee that the data has arrived.